# how to set background image url for local files?

Tags: html, vue.js

I want to paste a relative image url to a div to set it as the background image. Unfortunately the div won't render the image. So this works fine and renders the image

```
<img src="../assets/images/HeroImg.jpg">
```

but this one doesn't

```
<div style="background-image: url(../assets/images/HeroImg.jpg)">
    Content goes here
</div>
```

Things I also tried:

- wrapping the url inside single quotes
- `assets/images/HeroImg.jpg` maybe?
- `./assets/images/HeroImg.jpg` starting from the src folder
- `images/HeroImg.jpg` and `./images/HeroImg.jpg` starting from the assets folder

What is the correct url to use for background images?

---

**Update**

I'm using VueJs so things might be different here? Steps to reproduce:

- Create a new project using the Vue CLI
- Create a `images` directory in `src/assets`
- Create an image in `src/assets/images` and call it `HeroImg`
- Update App.vue file with

.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>
      This works:
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="./assets/images/HeroImg.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
      This doesn't work:
    </div>
    <div style="background-image: url('./assets/images/HeroImg.jpg')">
        Content without background image
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

You will see that the img tag renders the image but not the div with the background image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using relative paths, Webpack is unable to resolve them properly if they are found inside your inline `style` attributes. Webpack, can, however, resolve the image path properly if it is use as an `<img>` element source in the template directly. Therefore, the solution to use a resolved image path as a CSS attribute is to simply **reference it as a computed property**.

In your template, you can use `v-bind:style="heroImage"` to reference a computed property:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-bind:style="heroImage">
        Content without background image
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then, in your VueJS component itself, you can do:

```
computed: {
  heroImage() {
    return {
      backgroundImage: `url${require('../assets/images/HeroImg.jpg')}`
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Terry's answer did the trick but I needed an extra set of parentheses around the `url` tag content:

```
computed: {
  heroImage() {
    return {
      backgroundImage: `url(${require('../assets/images/HeroImg.jpg')})`
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div class="yourDivClass">
    Content goes here
</div>
```

css

```
.yourDivClass {
  background: url('../assets/images/HeroImg.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover
}
```

Comment: sorry but is there a html solution for this? because the url is dynamic

Comment: just add the url in the url(' ') property in your css and it will still work

Comment: sorry but I already tried that. This doesn't work for me (I'm using VueJs)

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap them with quotes.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image), we need to wrap the path or url of the image into a

> background-image: url("../../media/examples/lizard.png");

```
<div style="background-image: url(../assets/images/HeroImg.jpg)">
    Content goes here
</div>
```

**Suggestion:**

Better to avoid the inline styles. you can include the style in an external sheet.

Comment: sorry but I already tried that. This doesn't work for me (I'm using VueJs)

Answer (score 0):

Try in css file like this

```
background-image: url('~src/assets/home-page-img/header-bg.jpg');
```

Comment: in my case worked like this `background-image: url('src/assets/home-page-img/header-bg.jpg');`

Answer (score -1):

I think you have not specified height and width property.

```css
div {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.skillcrush.com/skillcrush/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Blog_coding-game.jpg.webp)"></div>
```

Comment: sorry but I already tried that. This doesn't work for me (I'm using VueJs)