# Background-image url() doesn't work but image tag with src does

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

currently working in vue 3 and tailwind css, the path works with src but not with url, I have exhausted all the information I can find but can't seem to figure out the problem, I believe the file path must be correct since src is able to locate it

```
<template>
  <div
    class="absolute top-0 w-full h-full bg-center bg-cover"
    style="background-image: url(../assets/images/unsplash.png)"
  >
    <span id="blackOverlay" class="w-full h-full absolute opacity-75 bg-black"></span>
   <div>
     <img src="../assets/images/unsplash.png" alt="">
   </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set background image url for local files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60916989/how-to-set-background-image-url-for-local-files)

Comment: Use your dev tools and check in the network tab which image gets loaded. If you remove the img from your code you don't have content. And then you can't see the image, but it would be loaded anyway

Answer (score 0):

The url to the image should be into simple quotes :)
Try this :

```
style="background-image: url('../assets/images/unsplash.png')"
```

Sincerely,
Alex ;)

Comment: Tried that too but doesn’t work, according to docs quotes aren’t necessary